# Returning data in non tabular form from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join

Pardon me for the vague title, but I could not find more appropriate words for summarizing my problem.

In the database there are two tables that I want to combine and retrieve data from:

```
Id   Name     Description               Id       Batch    Quantity
1    Item_A     ....                     1         1A       25
2    Item_B     ....                     1         1B       25
3    Item_C     ....                     1         1C       50
.                                        1         1D       50
.                                        2         2A       21
                                         .          .        .
                                         .          .        .
```

I want combine the from the data in second table with its corresponding Id in the first table,
that is providing the appropriate name and description for the Batches of items.

A simple join does give me the data that I want, but joining the two tables produces a large table in which the the description column is repeated for every Batch with the same Id even though only one Description data for the same Id would be sufficient.

**Is there any way that combines the Name and Description data to the corresponding Id value in the second table, but that does not produce redundant data, in which the Name and the fairly long Description column is not repeated for the same Id?**

One solution that I have tried, is to retrieve the two tables separately, but by sorting according to the Id in the same order. In this way I can use simple mapping function to create a pseudo object like this:

```
Main{
   List<Item> Items
}
Item{
   string Name
   string Description
   List<Quantity> Quantities
}
Quantity{
    string Batch
    int Quantity
}
```

However this breaks the data manipulation step in two languages and will make the code complicated and harder to understand.

Preferably, I want to retrieve the data for all the items at once(with the execution of a stored procedure once). Can somebody show be a good way to do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you are asking for is something normally carried out by the front end, not in the query itself. Either pull the redundant data, or pull the data in 2 queries to avoid duplicating data. Also add your current SQL.

Comment: You can select which columns you want from the joined tables.

Comment: @DaleK I am using sql-server 2014. I was wondering if something like that would be done in database itself, or if not, if there was a better approach.

Comment: @j1mbl3s I want all the columns,(because I wanted at least one Name and Description for each Id) but wanted to avoid the redundant data

Comment: Better approach is not to do it in the database.

Comment: @DaleK ok, thanks for the tip

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you *can* do it there... I just wouldn't. If you want to, just use window functions to detect when a given column changes and null the column the rest of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use XML.

Here is how to produce parent/child one-to-many XML in MS SQL Server.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @parent TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, ItemName VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @parent (ID, ItemName) VALUES
(1, 'Item_A'),
(2, 'Item_B');

DECLARE @child TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ParentID INT, Batch CHAR(2), Quantity INT);
INSERT INTO @child (ParentID,  Batch,  Quantity) VALUES
(1, '1A', 25),
(1, '1B', 25),
(1, '1C', 50),
(2, '1D', 50),
(2, '2A', 21);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT p.*
    , (
    SELECT c.* 
    FROM @child AS c
    WHERE c.ParentID = p.ID
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('child')
)    
FROM @parent AS p
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <r>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ItemName>Item_A</ItemName>
    <child>
      <r>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <ParentID>1</ParentID>
        <Batch>1A</Batch>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
      </r>
      <r>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <ParentID>1</ParentID>
        <Batch>1B</Batch>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
      </r>
      <r>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <ParentID>1</ParentID>
        <Batch>1C</Batch>
        <Quantity>50</Quantity>
      </r>
    </child>
  </r>
  <r>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ItemName>Item_B</ItemName>
    <child>
      <r>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <ParentID>2</ParentID>
        <Batch>1D</Batch>
        <Quantity>50</Quantity>
      </r>
      <r>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <ParentID>2</ParentID>
        <Batch>2A</Batch>
        <Quantity>21</Quantity>
      </r>
    </child>
  </r>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will try to apply this to my solution.